# Power Query/DAX to calculate monthly raw sales figure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

**Dear stackoverflow, please help!**

I'm hoping for some assistance with data processing in Power BI, either using Power Query or DAX. At this point I am really stuck and can't figure out how to solve this problem.

The below table is a list of sales by Product, Month, and Year. The problem with my data is that the value in the sales data is actually cumulative, rather than the raw figure of sales for that month. In other words, the figure is the sum of the number of sales for the month (for that  Year and Product combination) and the number of sales for the preceding month. As you will see in the table below, the number gets progressively larger in each category as the year progresses. The true number of sales for TVs in Feb of 2021, for example, is the sales figure of 3 minus the corresponding figure for sales of TVs in Jan of 2021 (1).

I really would appreciate if anyone knows of a solution to this problem. In reality, my table has hundreds of thousands of rows, so I cannot do the calculations manually.

Is there a way to use Power Query or DAX to create a calculated column with the Raw Sales figure for each month? Something that would check if Product and Year are equal, then subtract the Jan figure from the Feb figure and so on?

Any help will be very much appreciated,

**Sales Table**

| Product | Sales (YTD) | Month | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TV | 1 | Jan | 2021 |
| Radio | 4 | Jan | 2021 |
| Cooker | 5 | Jan | 2021 |
| TV | 3 | Feb | 2021 |
| Radio | 5 | Feb | 2021 |
| Cooker | 6 | Feb | 2021 |
| TV | 3 | Mar | 2021 |
| Radio | 6 | Mar | 2021 |
| Cooker | 8 | Mar | 2021 |
| TV | 5 | Apr | 2021 |
| Radio | 7 | Apr | 2021 |
| Cooker | 8 | Apr | 2021 |
| TV | 7 | May | 2021 |
| Radio | 8 | May | 2021 |
| Cooker | 8 | May | 2021 |
| TV | 9 | Jun | 2021 |
| Radio | 10 | Jun | 2021 |
| Cooker | 10 | Jun | 2021 |
| TV | 10 | Jul | 2021 |
| Radio | 10 | Jul | 2021 |
| Cooker | 10 | Jul | 2021 |
| TV | 11 | Aug | 2021 |
| Radio | 13 | Aug | 2021 |
| Cooker | 12 | Aug | 2021 |
| TV | 11 | Sep | 2021 |
| Radio | 13 | Sep | 2021 |
| Cooker | 12 | Sep | 2021 |
| TV | 12 | Oct | 2021 |
| Radio | 14 | Oct | 2021 |
| Cooker | 13 | Oct | 2021 |
| TV | 17 | Nov | 2021 |
| Radio | 19 | Nov | 2021 |
| Cooker | 17 | Nov | 2021 |
| TV | 19 | Dec | 2021 |
| Radio | 20 | Dec | 2021 |
| Cooker | 20 | Dec | 2021 |
| TV | 4 | Jan | 2022 |
| Radio | 2 | Jan | 2022 |
| Cooker | 3 | Jan | 2022 |
| TV | 5 | Feb | 2022 |
| Radio | 3 | Feb | 2022 |
| Cooker | 5 | Feb | 2022 |

Thanks, Jim

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try in powerquery / M.   It groups on Product and Year, then  sorts the months, and subtracts each row from the next row to determine the period amount.

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Product", "Year"}, {
    {"data", each 
    let r=Table.Sort(Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1),{ each List.PositionOf({"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"}, [Month]), {"Month",Order.Ascending}}),
    x= Table.AddColumn( r,  "Period Sales", each if [Index]=0 then [#"Sales (YTD)"] else [#"Sales (YTD)"]-r{[Index]-1}[#"Sales (YTD)"])
    in x
    , type table }
    }),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Sales (YTD)", "Month", "Period Sales"}, {"Sales (YTD)", "Month", "Period Sales"})
in  #"Expanded data"
```

[image]